# What is the closed form of the given integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Does a closed form of integral for $$\int_a^b e^{-c \left( x+\frac{a}{x}\right)} dx$$ exist? How can I approximate such integral?

Here, $a=0^+$ (greater than $0$) and c is a positive constant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no elementary solution. You need to use numeric methods. If you have error limitations (error < number) use Trapezoid rule or simpson rule with necessary partition. If the upper limit b is close to zero, you can use taylor series. Then you are going to integrate some terms by hand and compute the result. Bear in mind that it is not possible to foreseen error limits in this method.